# как мне выполнить db:migrate на RubyOnRails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Всем привет! Делаю пример по [Tutorial](http://railstutorial.ru/chapters/4_0/a-demo-app#sec-demo_users_resource) и запинка на выполнении `$ bundle exec rake db:migrate`, получаю такой вывод:

```
@:~/rails/demo % bundle exec rake db:migrate
config.eager_load is set to nil. Please update your config/environments/*.rb files accordingly:

   * development - set it to false
   * test - set it to false (unless you use a tool that preloads your test environment)
   * production - set it to true

rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `whitelist_attributes=' for #<Class:0x0000080d034c78>

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => db:load_config
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Какие мои должны быть действия?

*добавлено* Теперь после предпринятых действий описанных в комментариях, нужны разъяснения что все это значит.

Comment: после того как закомментировал в  config/application.rb параметр ` config.active_record.whitelist_attributes` имею ошибку `NoMethodError: undefined method 'mass_assignment_sanitizer=' for #<Class:0x0000080cf090d8>`

Comment: закомментировал в конфигурациях `config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer` и `config.active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds`

Comment: теперь получаю только `config.eager_load is set to nil. Please update your config/environments/*.rb files accordingly:`

Comment: сообщение пропало после прописывания в production.rb `config.eager_load = true`, а в остальных config/environments/*.rb `config.eager_load = false`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас в файлах сред не был задан `config.eager_load` -- потому он имел значение `nil`. А он должен быть определён -- иметь значение `true` или `false`. Интересно то, что [с Rails 4.0.1](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/11389) при миграциях этот параметр должен игнорироваться, т. к. задан в задании -- но проверка на существование, видимо, всё равно происходит.

Возможно, вы генерировали приложение [третьими рельсами](http://pivotallabs.com/rails-4-upgrade/), где этой опции ещё не было. Как это произошло, затрудняюсь сказать. Возможно, вы отклонились от инструкций в книге. Там много маленьких, но острых деталей, из-за которых что-нибудь может пойти не так. Сам на этом спотыкался пару раз. Генератор у Rails 4 выдаёт готовое к запуску приложение, у которого эти опции в файлах сред уже выставлены.

Comment: да я видел что работаю с rails3, но пошел дальше делать не обращая на это внимания; дело у меня в том что я ставил на FreeBSD пакет rubygem-rails, а для rails4 надо rubygem-rails4

Comment: @dile с этим должен справляться Bundler, если в гемфайле явно указана версия рельс.